# Dimming the buttons in windows phone 8

Tags: button, windows-phone-8, brightness

I want to create a text entry app for windows phone 8 that is almost completely dark.

I can't find a way to dim the screen to less than the minimum brightness, so I've resorted to re-creating the keyboard and simulating a text field. It works fairly well, barring a few issues like a lack of word suggestions.

The main issue I have now is that the screen is almost completely dim, except for the backlight behind the hardware buttons at the base of the phone.

Is there any way to dim these?

Comment: you mean to change the background of the buttons?

Comment: Did you try reducing the 'Opacity' of the Page ?

Comment: @Kulasangar, no I meant dim the light behind the hardware buttons at the base of the phone

Comment: No, you cannot control the brightness of hardware buttons. Personally I let user or automatic settings to handle everything around brightness and don't try to "hack" it...